# UNIX shell script to monitor and copy file changes

Tags: shell, unix

Is there a way to monitor a file every minute or so and copy only the appended lines to another file? I am looking for a way to consolidate log files generated in multiple servers into a single file whenever logs are generated. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

would rsync help in this case?

Comment: Are those servers running on a single or on separate systems?

Comment: Running in a single system

Comment: This belongs on Unix&Linux. It wouldn't be *completely* out of place on SuperUser, but U&L seems like a better fit to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is just to use the tail command, I'd say:

```
tail -f /path1/file1 /path2/file2 /path3/file3 > shared.log
```

No latency, content is added in chronological order and you also get a fine marker between sections from different processes / log files.

You can start the process and keep in running in background after logout:

```
nohup tail -f /path1/file1 /path2/file2 /path3/file3 > shared.log &
```

Comment: This is awesome...I am just curious since you asked if the servers are running in a single or separate systems. How to do the same if the servers are running in different systems?

Comment: Not sure what is best, actually. You could try the same approach, running a single `tail` instance in each system, started from a ssh client and pump that into a central `tail` on the collecting system by means of piping. If you have access to the file systems you might also be able to use a single, central `tail` command, but that depends on the file servers. A monitoring system can also be fitted for this task, that makes sense if the systems are monitored anyway.

Comment: Or, probably the most robust would be to use something like gray logging. So a central "logging server" where remote processes can log things to. You could feed that by means of distributed `tail` commands again.